# Recompile executable from one platform to another

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, cross-platform, cpu-architecture

It seems like given a full reference of instructions for any two platforms, say x86 and ARM, it should be possible to convert a program compiled for the first platform to the second one. Those instructions that one of the platform lacks can be implemented as a series of more primitive instructions. Ultimately, what CPU does are I/O and arithmetic. If so, why people develop emulators that interpret code at a higher level rather than developing instruction translators which would allow to have binaries running at the native speed of the target platform?

Comment: Typically a lot of other things will differ between the systems (caches, memory protection units, gpus, audio hardware, etc). For some systems it might be sufficient to emulate these at a very high level, but for others - in particular old game consoles - you can often have strong timing sensitivity (cycle-counting code that writes to the gpu during the horizontal balnking period to do raster effetcs, just to mention one example). The approach also has problems with self-modifying code. Anyway, there was at least one N64 emulator that used static recompilation, and it worked in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called binary translation, and it is done in several applications. For example Intel performs binary translation of Android applications compiled for ARM. Some instructions can be translated easily, while others require more complex emulation.

Comment: Thanks for naming the exact term. Now it's easier to find more information.

Comment: another way to search for this static binary translation is...static...not running the code but analyzing and converting.  dynamic binary translation is while running the program is converted sometimes in portions rather than an attempt at the whole thing.  each approach has their pros and cons.

Comment: About that binary translation Intel performs: do you have some link to explanation?

Comment: good review:   http://blog.apedroid.com/2013/05/binary-translation-vs-native-x86-code.html